# aspx Request.Form.Count=0

Tags: asp.net, webforms, request.form

I am not getting any data when submitting a form. I would expect `Request.Form.Count=2`, but instead `RequestForm.Count=0`.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" EnableViewState="false" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb"     Inherits="ecomm_Default2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post">
        <input id="textfield" type="text" value="My Text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send it" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind part

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Partial Class ecomm_Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Request.HttpMethod = "POST" Then
            Debug.WriteLine(Request.Form.Count)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You input fields are missing names. Make sure you add them:

```
<input id="textfield" name="foo" type="text" value="My Text" />
<input type="submit" name="bar" value="Send it" />
```

Now on the server you will get both `foo` and `bar` keys with their respective values.

Comment: Well I knew it had to be something simple. Thank you very much!